# How can I take product shots of a flat (but not absolutely flat) reflective surface?

Tags: lighting, product-photography, glare

I need to make a photo of an iPhone case. The picture I've got with my rig used for other (non reflective) cases gave me the following result:

[image]

Which I don't like as it don't shows the reflective surface.

I tried to reflect articulated softbox in the front surface. But I get the following:

[image]

Don't look at the bad angle and uneven background - it's preproduction shot, my main concerns are:

- the roughness of the light glare
- accuracy needed to set the position of the subject

As you can see the glare is unpleasant. At least I'm far from being satisfied with both these images.

I'd be happy to get something like this:

[image]

But in my case the surface is not so flat on a macro (it is a rubber or something like that so it has some curvature) and micro (it has some grains) levels.

Can you suggest anything to make the shots better? My only thought is to draw the glare in Photoshop, but I have tons of those cases to take a shot so I'd better make a rig and save my time with postproduction.

UPD: I decided to make the glare in Photoshop. Of course it is a time consuming job, but I think that the natural glare will be also tricky to obtain and the quality will be probably not as expected. My current result is the following:

[image]

Comment: related   http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42871/overhead-shot-over-a-glossy-suface/42872#42872

Comment: @MichaelClark, these are not actually the answers to MY question :(Some tricks can be applied, so thanks for the link I read one carefully. However my subject is not a mirror as you can see from the samples I posted, so I don't need to avoid camera reflection (at least this problem is the least one). I'd like to make the glare more straight or something...

Comment: The glare in the reference picture most certainly was not done photographically; that is if that is a photo at all. And if you are interested in the result and not the process than you should do it that way also.

Comment: @his - The glare in the reference shot was almost certainly done photographically, and it's not even particularly difficult to accomplish. It's been cleaned up mercilessly, but apart from that it could have been shot on film. (You may note that you can see slightly more of the left side of the phone than you can of the right. That's a lens shift at work, but you can accomplish the same thing by putting the phone toward the right side of the frame and cropping. That, in turn, lets you place a white card so that it seems to reflect directly back at you without putting it in front of the lens.)